# How to get GET response on Android before redirection?

Tags: java, android, captivenetwork

I try to get HTTP data before redirection when Android tries to connect to Captive Portal.

Here is snippets of code:

```
        httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(/*params*/);

        String url = "http://google.com";

        Log.d("test_runner", "URL: " + url);

        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        if (entity != null) {
            entity.consumeContent();
        }


        for(Header h : response.getAllHeaders()){
            Log.d("test_runner", h.toString());
        }

        Log.d("test_runner", response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() + "");

        response.getStatusLine();
```

When I use `Fiddler Web Debugger` I see followed flow:

[image]

So 1st off I need receive status 302 and after redirect status 200.

However, I straight get response after redirection.

[image]

Sounds like Android does redirect automatically and I can't catch it.

**How can I fetch response information before redirection (a.e. 1st row from Fiddler, header of 302)?**

Thank you

Comment: this might be helpful http://blog.kosev.net/2011/01/follow-302-redirects-with.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution, (didn't think so quickly)

```
HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpClientParams.setRedirecting(params, false);

httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
....
```